# How can I use the same web files for a wordpress install, but change theme based on domain?

Tags: wordpress

I have a site that will be accessed using multiple domain names. It is a WordPress install. I am wondering if it is possible to make it so that if a user comes to domainname1.com that they see the site using theme1 and if they come to the site using domainname2.com they see the site using theme2? I don't want to use redirect and I don't want to use query strings to do this. I want it based on the URL. I assume there might be a way to do this using a .htaccess file.

Comment: Are both domains hosted on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try any of these?

1) Turn yoursite.com into a MultiSite

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

2) Add on Domain Mapping

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

3) use two different databases and update the config file.